# Use JQUERY in Typescript

Tags: jquery, typescript

I'm trying to intregate JQUERY into Typescript but I hit a brick wall and I don't know how to get over it. Bear in mind that I'm a newbie when it comes to Typescript (been messing with it for a couple of months only), so there is a chance that this problem is very easy to solve but I can't figure it out.

So, I have this very simple program in TS:

```
/// <reference path="node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts" />

function PrintName()
{
    let name:any = $('#txtName').val();
    console.log(name);
}
```

But when I run it in the web I get the error:  Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at PrintName

But, when I include this line in the HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It works just fine. So, how can I add Jquery to the Typescript ? I tried with this command:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/jquery
```

And then adding the reference to index.d.ts, but I get the same error. I'm using Visual Studio Code 1.27, tsc 3.0.1 and npm 3.5

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing `@types/jquery` only gives you type information for jQuery; you still have to load an implementation at runtime.  Using a separate `<script>` tag is OK.  If you want to produce a single JavaScript file that includes your code as well as libraries it depends on that are packaged in module form (such as jQuery), you'll need to use a module bundler such as Webpack, Rollup, or Browserify; the TypeScript compiler is not capable of doing this by itself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I would have to check those modules then. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

add dependencies: type in CLI.

```
npm --save jquery
npm --save jquery-ui-bundle
```

in angular-cli.json:

```
"scripts": [ 
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/jquery-ui-bundle/jquery-ui.js"], ...
```

then in your component use:

```
declare var jQuery:any; // jQuery is the same as $
```